# How to replace characters until matching character sequence?

Tags: vim

I know that in command mode, `ct{char}` removes all text from current cursor position till next matching `{char}`, which can then be replaced by continuing to type.

For example, suppose the text is:

```
abcdefgh
```

and cursor is on `b`, then typing `ctg` will remove `bcdef`, which can be replaced by continuing to type.

But this works only for a single matching character. Is it possible to do this by matching a character sequence, for example, using `gh` instead of `g`, in above example?

Note: I know that the `s///` could be used, but this is a little faster, and more convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Use the search command:

```
c/gh
```

The *search* is a motion for the previous command. So it will delete characters until if finds a `gh` string.

Comment: How does that help? I don't want to just search for it, I want to replace the text leading up to it from the current cursor position.

Comment: @Happy: I've edited the answer to add an explanation.